# tabbed panel showing up as Berger dots

Tags: xpages

I put a  tabbed panel on a page and it's showing up as Berger dots vertically.
It's very simple

Instead of showing up as tabs, it renders as:

```
o New Tab
o New Tab2
```

When I select 'New Tab', I see the label, when I select 'New Tab2', I see the button.
Any ideas on what's going on?

thanks
clem

Answer (score 0):

Something with your CSS is not working correctly. You are seeing an unformatted list. What theme are you using in your application?